# Searching for dataset related to empowerment of women in agriculture as a result of participation in a development program

Tags: usaidopen

I am searching for a dataset concerning the empowerment of women in agriculture that contains a variable that is related to participation in a development aid program.

My research question is: Do development aid programs empower women?

I have found the Feed the Future Datasets (Baseline Survey) from USAID Data, but it does not contain any variables/observations related to if and how women were supported by the Feed the Future Initiative.

Is there any dataset with variables concerning empowerment and an aid program?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much for posting here! I’m happy to help, and apologize for the notable delay while we were making important changes to the DDL that I hope you’ll find valuable.

We have a few datasets from the Feed the Future initiative that you might find interesting—in particular, the datasets that contain the underlying data for calculating the Women’s Empowerment in Agriculture Index, which you can find [here](https://data.usaid.gov/browse?q=Women%27s%20Empowerment%20in%20Agriculture%20Index&sortBy=relevance) or enter into the search bar in the [Data Catalog](https://data.usaid.gov/browse). At the moment, however, only the baseline surveys are available. As our data submitting partners collect and submit interim and endline surveys, they will be made available on the DDL.

Please don’t hesitate to follow up on this thread or email us at [dataservices@usaid.gov](http://mailto:dataservices@usaid.gov) if you have any other questions.

Hope this helps!

Robin, USAID Data Services